# Sending nested arrays as POST datas in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to send post datas to my server.

```
$url = 'http://my_server';

$data = http_build_query(array(
  "conditions" => [
    ["id", "1", "equal"],
    ["jd", array("a" => "b",
                 "c" => "d"), "equal"]
  ]
));

$options = array(
    'http' => array (
        'method' => 'POST',
        'ignore_errors' => true,
        'content' => $data
    )
);

$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $options);
```

On my server where the code is in `ruby`, I receive the parameters as

> Parameters: {"conditions"=>{"1"=>{"0"=>"jd", "1"=>{"c"=>"d", "a"=>"b"}, "2"=>"equal"}, "0"=>{"0"=>"id", "1"=>"1", "2"=>"equal"}}

While I would like to receive

> Parameters: {"conditions"=>[["id", "1", "equal"], ["jd", {"c"=>"d", "a"=>"b"}, "equal"]]

What can I do? Do I need to use an other way to send my datas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Send them with JSON instead? This maintains the integrity of the entire array.

Comment: Finally what I did with cURL.